# How to Insert Row to Parent Table and another Table while in the Parent Table Create Form? - ASP MVC 5

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For example I have a table called 'Child' which is connected to another table (one-to-many relationship) to another table called 'Siblings'. What I want to do is that in the 'Child' Create Form I also have a sub-form with the field for 'Siblings' table (like 'name', 'age', etc.)

The problem is the 'sibling' Table has a foreign key connected to 'child'. And, when the user clicks on Submit in 'child' Create Form (together with the sub-form for the 'sibling' Table) there will be an error because the 'child' row has not yet been created resulting to no foreign keys yet.

Thus, is there a way to simultaneously make an Insert in 'child' and 'sibling' Table using one Create Form?

Note: I am using the ADO.NET Entity Framework to create the Controllers and Views for both tables/models. I am also using MySQL for VS2015 Community.

This is my 'child' Model:

```
public partial class child
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public child()
    {
        this.siblings = new HashSet<sibling>();
    }

    public int child_id { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string middle_name { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> age { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<sibling> siblings { get; set; }
}
```

This is my 'sibling' Model:

```
 public partial class sibling
{
    public int sibling_id { get; set; }
    public int child_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> age { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }

    public virtual child child { get; set; }
}
```

Screenshot of the .EDMX:
[My .EDMX diagram screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuM79.png)

Comment: can you put your data models ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @Sampath Placed it already!

Comment: @JimHawkins Sorry about that. I am new to asking questions here. Thank you!